# Pass variable to http.request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, servlets

How to pass and retrieve an variable to http.request() in nodejs.

```
var URL = 'parent/test';
var isParentSenior = true;
var output = '';
var options = {
host: config.ip,
path: config.rest_prefix + URL,
method: 'POST',
rejectUnauthorized: false,
headers: {
'Authorization': token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(input, 'utf8'),
'Browser': userUtil.detectBrowserNameAndVersion(req.headers[`user-agent`]),
'ip_address': req.headers[`x-forwarded-for`]
  }
};
var reqPost = https.request(options, function (resPost) {
                resPost.on('data', function (d) {
                    output = output + d;
                });
                resPost.on('end', function () {
                    logger.info('Final POST result***:\n' + output);
```

Post Method to retrieve the isParent variable.

```
@POST
@Path("parent/test")
public Response addParent(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response){
  // How to get the variable isParentSenior
}
```

Comment: For a GET request, you can pass data with the request either in a custom header, in the request path itself or in a query parameter at the end of the URL.  It really depends upon where your server is expecting to find the data.

Comment: @jfriend00 its post method.

Comment: Then for a POST, you can also pass the data in the body of the request with an appropriate content-type header that describes the format of the data in the body.   Typical content-types used for this are  `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not getting it. Can u provide the solution maybe I can try.

Comment: Is the server under your control so you can send the data any way you want and write the server request handler to work that way or is the server already coded and expecting the data to arrive in a specific way?

Comment: server under my control as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're interested in following REST principles, the best way to send the data with a POST would depend upon what the request is doing and what this data means.  If you're creating a new parent record on the server and `isParentSenior` is one of the properties of that new record, then it would be appropriate to send the data as a JSON-serialized object in the body of the POST request.  But, to create a new record, I would assume you probably need more data than just that one field.  But, with just that one field, here's how it would look:

```
const URL = 'parent/test';
const isParentSenior = true;
const options = {
    host: config.ip,
    path: config.rest_prefix + URL,
    method: 'POST',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

const reqPost = https.request(options, function (resPost) {
    let output = '';
    resPost.on('data', function (d) {
        output = output + d;
    });
    resPost.on('end', function () {
        logger.info('Final POST result***:\n' + output);
    });
});
const postData = {
    isParentSenior
};
reqPost.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
reqPost.end();
```

Your server will then get the POST request with a body that contains the result of `JSON.stringify(postData)` and it will have to parse that JSON so it can access the `isParentSenior` property in the resulting object.

---

If the `isParentSenior` variable is part of some query specification (less likely if this is a POST that is creating a new record on the server), then you would send it as text in the path as in `/parent/test/1` or `/parent/test/0` or you could send it as part the query string as in `/parent/test?isParentSenior=1` or `/parent/test?isParentSenior=0`.